# Create a workspace from Powershell run within VS Team Services build

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am writing a Powershell script as part of a Visual Studio Team Services build, this build uses a hosted build controller. The script is intended to check out a file, make changes then check it back in.

In the script I am trying to invoke the `tf` command to create a new workspace but I'm having authentication issues. The command

```
& $tf vc workspace /new $tempWorkspaceName /collection:https://mycollection.visualstudio.com/
```

produces the error:

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://mycollection.visualstudio.com/.

How can I access TFS from my Powershell script without embedding logins or passwords in the script? Can I access TFS within the context of the build agent, which itself logs in to TFS? Or is there another way I should be doing this?

Note that I haven't used the TFS Power Tool cmdlets as it is a hosted build server. Using the TFS RestAPI also doesn't appear to be an option as there is no facility to check a file in or out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token option of your build defition
   [image]
2. Append **/noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$(System.AccessToken)** to your TF command (arguments)

About TF Command, you can check [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workspace-command) article.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. All the doco I had seen used the AccessToken as part of a REST call, I didn't see it used on the command line like that.

Comment: Where is this documented? Which version of tf.exe? It seems unsupported with vc14 :\