# OAuth usage in tf.exe

Tags: powershell, tfs, oauth, tf-cli

I'm trying to run a powershell script as a build step for TFS2015. In the script I have `tf history /r /noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`, as I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736569/308421) answer, but I get the following error: `TF10120: The value OAuth is not supported for option loginType.`

Moreover, I don't see any documentation for the `/logintype` option. Was it deprecated / not supported in Visual studio 2015?

What can I do to call tf commands from my script with proper authorization?

Answer (score 1):

This is not documented anywhere, you could find related info after enable `system.debug=true` in a build definition, then check the build log for TF command related. For example, in the get source task, there should be something like:

`tf vc workspaces /format:xml /collection:https://tfs.MyCompany.net/tfs/Collection/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt`

According to your error message, seems the built-in `tf.exe` does not supports OAuth on your build agent.

As a workaround you could use the `/login:username,password`: If you want to run the command as another user, you must specify the /login option verbatim, replace username with the name of the user, and if necessary, you can supply the password.

Details please refer this thread: [Use /login option to specify credentials when running a command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands#use-options-to-modify-how-a-command-functions)

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of VSTS I was experiencing the same symptons when using this PowerShell script - $AccessToken is passed as $(System.AccessToken).

```
Param(
  [string]$AccessToken
)

if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe") { "TF.exe Exists" }

$TFFile = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"

Write-Host [string](& $TFFile.FullName vc workspaces /collection:*<collection name>* /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$AccessToken)
```

However, when I used **Name** (TF.exe) instead of **FullName** in the script I was able to get it to work. The following script is working

```
Param(
  [string]$AccessToken
)

if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe") { "TF.exe Exists" }

$TFFile = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"

Write-Host [string](& $TFFile.Name vc workspaces /collection:*<collection name>* /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$AccessToken)
```

The other difference I have with your original command line was the addition of the *vc* part. This I mimicked from the commands that are run when the code is pulled from source control (Get Sources)

Comment: Yeah, I believe tf.exe version 14.* does not support /logintype. In your case it's working probably because you have tf.exe version 15+ installed and available from path.